# Google Map API creating Marker Error (Javascript API)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a hard time creating a function to create marker on the google Map.
Below is the current javascript code I have.

As you can see, I have created a map using `new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')`.

Then I created a `createMarker` function and trying to use that function to create a new marker just by passing `lat, lng, draggable` parameter.

However, when I run this, I am keep getting:

> map.createMarker is not a function.

Can someone please help me with this?

```js
function initMap() {
  // var fullstack = {lat: 40.705523, lng: -74.009149};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 16 ,
    center: {lat: 40.705523, lng: -74.009149},
    disableDefaultUI: false
  });

  var marker = map.createMarker(40.705523, -74.009149, true);

  var createMarker = function(lat, lng, draggable) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },
      map: map,
      draggable: draggable
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your createMarker function is not associated with the map.  Change `map.createMarker(...)` to `createMarker(...)`
2. When you declare a function as a variable, order matters. You need to declare the function before you use it.

**Working code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  // var fullstack = {lat: 40.705523, lng: -74.009149};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 16 ,
    center: {lat: 40.705523, lng: -74.009149},
    disableDefaultUI: false
  });
  var createMarker = function(lat, lng, draggable) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },
      map: map,
      draggable: draggable
    })
  }
  var marker = createMarker(40.705523, -74.009149, true);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

createMarker is not a function, mapped to map object, try calling createMarker as i did here.

```js
function initMap() {
  // var fullstack = {lat: 40.705523, lng: -74.009149};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 18,
    maxZoom: 19,
    minZoom: 16 ,
    center: {lat: 40.705523, lng: -74.009149},
    disableDefaultUI: false
  });

  var marker = createMarker(40.705523, -74.009149, true);

  var createMarker = function(lat, lng, draggable) {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      },
      map: map,
      draggable: draggable
    })
  }
}
```